# Computing view size

Tags: ember.js

I try to compute the view width each time the model is modified.
The template is calling the view.labelStyle computed property binded to the model
I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

I think my error is due to the $(this).outerWidth() call... but I do not know what it the correct way to call the JQuery method outerWidth() on the Ember view...

```
Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div class="secondary-field-label" {{bindAttr style="view.labelStyle"}}>

labelStyle: function() {
      var width=$(this).outerWidth());
      return 'width:' + width + 'px';
    }.property('content.label', 'content.value'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have access via:

```
var width = this.$().outerWidth();
```

Comment: I have tried that but I have an error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded... it seems a loop is there :(

Comment: It seems awkward to try to set the width of your view manually to a width, which is calculated based on the box model. This would again increase the outerwidth and so on. What do you want to achieve with this function?

Comment: I need to compute dynamic padding regarding views embedded in a parent view....this.$().outerWidth(); is working yet (I have found the loop...)